# Is there any way to get around the 50 recipient limit in the Gmail API?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

As mentioned, I am hitting a road block in getting a simple script in google apps script to work properly. Essentially, I need to create an email draft with ~60 recipients - Google only allows up to 50 recipients to my knowledge (via using an apps script). Are there any work arounds for this within the apps script? Here is a link to the quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas . My code below if that helps.

```
function doGet() {
  createDraft();
  return;
}

// this function grabs the correct emails from the google doc, outputs them separated by commas
function getEmails() {
  const documentID = 'MY_DOCUMENT_ID';
  const recipients = DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getBody().getText().split(/\n/).join(',');
  Logger.log(recipients);
  return recipients;
}

// this creates the email draft with the list of recipients
function createDraft() {
  GmailApp.createDraft(getEmails(), 'SUBJECT', 'BODY TEXT');
}
```

And I receive this message after running:

> Error - - - - - - Exception: Limit Exceeded: Email Recipients Per Message

So I'm pretty confident I am doing it right, and not confident that there is a solution, but if anyone knows any work arounds for this type of thing I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function getEmails() {
  const documentID = 'MY_DOCUMENT_ID';
  const recipients = DocumentApp.openById(documentID).getBody().getText().split(/\n/);
  Logger.log(recipients);
  return recipients;
}

// this creates the email draft with the list of recipients
function createDraft() {
  const r = getEmails();
  GmailApp.createDraft(r.slice(0,50).join(','), 'SUBJECT', 'BODY TEXT');
  //may need some Utilities.sleep() in here dont know
  GmailApp.createDraft(r.slice(50).join(','), 'SUBJECT', 'BODY TEXT');
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a solution! Although I would prefer that it only creates one draft instead of two. But this could totally work.

Answer (score 2):

Apps Script services have daily [quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) and limitations on some features to prevent abuse of the services.

Two workarounds that I could suggest:

1. Breaking the recipient list just like @Cooper answered. With this option, keep in mind that the mail recipients quota per day is 100 for Gmail accounts.
2. Add recipients to a [group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/2464926) and send the email to the group email address instead.